# How to use WebAccountManager in UWP to authenticate app using Window Credentials

Tags: xamarin, active-directory, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-authentication

I'm trying to use WebAccountManager as [suggested](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/08/03/develop-windows-universal-apps-with-azure-ad-and-the-windows-10-identity-api/) for my organization link at https://si.business360online.com/ It can be logged in using same account as Windows User(on orgnization domain). I'm not able to get any token or existing account from Windows 10 PC.

I have also tried the `AccountsSettingsPane` with `WebAccountProvider` as follows:

```
AccountsSettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().AccountCommandsRequested += OnlineDataStore_AccountCommandsRequested;
AccountsSettingsPane.Show();
```

and then `OnlineDataStore_AccountCommandsRequested` is as follows:

```
WebAccountProvider wap = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync("https://si.business360online.com/");

but wap is always null.
```

<del>Can anybody help on how to login through Windows Credentials of current logged in user in UWP?</del> Using following more R&D I'm able to login as Windows current user, but in Windows.Web.Http, I'm not able to control the logout/clear credentials etc.

**Edit 1:** Following code snippets works but `System.Net.Http` may be deprected in future versions.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
handler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
System.Net.Http.message = await httpClient.GetAsync(feedUrl);
```

**Edit 2:** This might be helpful to someone: To enable Windows authentication in UWP/Windows Mobile, it is must to enable [Enterprise Capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#special-and-restricted-capabilities). Following points I found:

- For `System.Net.Http` we can control credentials by setting `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`
- For `Windows.Web.Http`, it will automatically log in as Windows Credentials if no credentials are set in `HttpProtocolFilter`.

Comment: So even System.Net.Http might be deprecated in the future, will the alternative Microsoft.Net.Http work for you?

Comment: Looks like you need to get the information for the domain windows user, there's an UWP code sample project https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo to do such.

Comment: @Jackie, I didn't go much deep in samples, but WebAccountManager didn't work for me. What worked for me is written in `Edit 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable Windows authentication in UWP/Windows Mobile, it is must to enable [Enterprise Capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#special-and-restricted-capabilities). (Same has been edited in question)

- For `System.Net.Http` we can control credentials by setting `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`
- For `Windows.Web.Http`, it will automatically log in as Windows Credentials if no credentials are set in `HttpProtocolFilter`.